# proving these assertions

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

The assertion is the following $f(n) \in O(n) \rightarrow f(n)^2 \in O(n^2)$
Here is my idea since $f(n) \in O(n)$ then $\exists c > 0 : f(n) \leq cn $
thus $f(n)^2 \leq c^2 n^2 \iff f(n)^2 \in O(n^2)$
correct?
the second one is $f(n) \in O(n) \rightarrow 2^{f(n)} \in O(2^n)$
Here is my idea since $f(n) \in O(n)$ then $\exists c > 0 : f(n) \leq cn \iff 2^{f(n)} \leq 2^{cn} = 2^c \cdot 2^n = \lambda 2^n \iff 2^{f(n)} \in O(2^n)$
Valid too?

Comment: Yes all looks fine

Comment: @LucaArmstrong Infinite gratitude!

Comment: But you should use absolute values when using O-notation, i.e. $|f(n)| < cn$

Comment: It doesn't change much here though